# Word Cloud Project has no errors but won't show the word cloud

Tags: python

I am doing the Coursera Python crash course and working on the final project.  I have no errors but the word cloud will not show.  This is relatively new to me, but I don't know why the word cloud isn't showing but no error is either.  Is there something I am missing to get the word cloud generated?  It is done in Jupyter, so the uploaded file happens beforehand.  That caused me problems when I stopped in the middle of the project and restarted later.  The upload did not stay, then I had to rerun that code to get the browse button to upload my file again.  Perhaps that is the problem?  Thank you!

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    for i in file_contents:
        if i in punctuations:
            file_contents = file_contents.replace(i, '')
            
    word_list = file_contents.split()
    
    frequency_dict = {}
    for word in word_list:
        if word in uninteresting_words:
            pass
        elif word.lower() not in frequency_dict and word.isalpha():
            frequency_dict[word.lower()] = 1
        elif word in frequency_dict and word.isalpha():
            frequency_dict[word.lower()] += 1
    
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequency_dict)
    return cloud.to_array()

# Display your wordcloud image

    myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
    plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: Ha!  I did not, that was it.  Thank you so much!  I can't believe I forgot that.